# How to use REVTeX's ruledtabular in a normal document?

Tags: tables, packages, revtex

I would like to use the `ruledtabular` environment in a book I am currently writing.

```
\begin{table}
\caption{\label{tab:table1}  ...}
\begin{ruledtabular}
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
   ...
\end{tabular}
\end{ruledtabular}
\end{table}
```

The problem is I don't want to begin with

```
\documentclass[preprint,...]{revtex4-1}
```

but with the normal

```
\documentclass{book}
```

Is there a way to do something like

```
\usepackage{revtex4-1}
```

?

Comment: This will be difficult. Revtex is not designed to be broken up this way, but you could attempt to go through the sources and pull out only the definition of the ruledtabular environment, and the commands necessary to implement it.

Comment: You can just use [booktabs](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) instead.

Comment: @Andrey: Please turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: @lockstep: Done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per REVTeX 4.1 guide, the two main features of `ruledtabular` are double rules and page wide tables. This can be achieved using two `\hline`-s in a row and the [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Something}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XX}
    \hline\hline
    Some & content \\
    \hline\hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Personally to me the two features look doubtful at best from the typographic point of view. I recommend reading the [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package documentation for good table typesetting practices.